# Using numlock for Trendnet KVM switch no longer works

Tags: unity, numlock, kvm-switch

I have a Trendnet TK-209 KVM switch, and since upgrading to 11.10, I can no longer switch between systems using numlock-numlock from ubuntu. (I also tried scrlk-scrlk).  If I switch manually to my windows box, I can get back to the ubuntu system with numlock-numlock, so it's not a problem with the keyboard or KVM switch.

Is there a setting that will allow this to work again, or an alternative keystroke?  Failing that, is there a way to configure the switch to allow it to be triggered from ubuntu?

Edited to add:

This may be a gnome 3.x problem, since I tried booting with a Fedora Live CD and it was also unable to use either key sequence to switch over to the other system.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I use Level One KVM switch - Num lock switch not working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and gleaned the answer from a post by George at http://beitis.net/ubuntu-kvm-switches-and-scroll-lock/

Basically, the workaround is to go to the console (Control + Alt + F1) and do the Num Lock there. I had to hit it 3 times to activate the switch.  When you come back to this machine it will still be in the console so do Control + Alt + F7 to get to the GUI.

[edit] Nah, twice works too.

Comment: It seems like sometimes it's 3, sometimes 2 - not sure what's going on, but this is an acceptable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Also see alternative solution using numlockx and an sh script.

1. Install numlockx

   ```
   sudo apt-get install numlockx
   ```
2. Create a script on desktop (KVM.sh)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   numlockx on;
   sleep 1; 
   numlockx off;
   sleep 1; 
   numlockx on
   ```
3. Create a custom keyboard shortcut to point to KVM.sh script (I used the key +K to execute this script)

See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11789416

Answer (score 0):

A quick note:

Under the 12.04 final beta.

- this now works as expected.